# Disable and Enable click event on div from button type

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, prop

I'm building Simon colors game with jQuery and I'm trying to disable the click event while the game is off or the player clicked on the wrong color. I'd read on the internet about the .prop('disalbe', true) and about .attr('disabled', 'disabled') but rn both of them didn't work for me. ***I'm using divs and not buttons elements***

```
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

```
allButtons.click(function() { // CLICK EVENT LISTENER
  const userChosenColour = this.id;
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);
  const userButton = $(`#${this.id}`);

  userButton.fadeTo(100, 0.1, function() { $(this).fadeTo(500, 1.0); });
  makeSound(this.id)


  if (checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length)) { // CONDITIONS TO CHECK THE CURRENT CLICK
    if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
      title.text('Success')
      setTimeout(function() {nextSequence()}, 1000);
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    // allButtons.attr('disabled',true);
    title.text('Wrong');
    makeSound('wrong');
    flashBackground();
    allButtons.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() {resetGame()}, 500);
    return false;
  }
});
```

rn the result is nothing happen. thank you for your help here !

Comment: Setting the `disabled` attribute won't work here because `<div>` elements don't have an enabled or disabled state. Please **do** use buttons if possible, as the browser will know that the user is able to interact with them. Setting `type="button"` on an arbitrary element doesn't make it a button, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the CSS property `pointer-events` to `none` to prevent clicks.

```js
allButtons.css('pointer-events', 'none'); // Disable clicks
allButtons.css('pointer-events', ''); // Re-enable
```